# Is it possible to make JToggle text depend on its state?

Tags: java, swing, jtogglebutton, itemlistener, changelistener

Is it possible for me to set the text on JToggle button to "ON" if it is selected and if not, as "OFF"?
I'm trying with this code:

```
    if(togbut.isSelected()){
        togbut.setText("ON");
    }
     else if(!togbut.isSelected()){
           togbut.setText("OFF");
    }
```

But it doesn't work. 
I use NetBeans 7.3.

Comment: Where have you put this code? In a Listener which you have registered on change events of that toggle button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is almost correct.

It has to be put in the change listener of your toggle button.

```
    toggleButton.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {
            if (toggleButton.isSelected()){
                toggleButton.setText("ON");
            } else {
                toggleButton.setText("OFF");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: or ItemListener, ActionListner

Answer (score 2):

You have to attach an `ItemListener` to that toggle button:

```
final JToggleButton togbut = new JToggleButton();
togbut.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            togbut.setText("ON");
        } else {
            togbut.setText("OFF");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Um Try this:

```
JToggleButton togbut = new JToggleButton("Click");
togbut.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
      if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        togbut.setText("ON");
      } else if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
        togbut.setText("OFF");
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an action listener to your togbut:

```
togbut.AddActionListener(this);
```

And add your code in the ActionPerformed() method.
Also I don't think a JToggleButton can have other state than `Selected` and `!Selected`
So you can changee your if structure to this:

```
if(togbut.isSelected()){
    togbut.setText("ON");
} else {
    togbut.setText("OFF");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ItemListener` interface to the class, where you use your `JToggleButton`. The implementation should like this:

```
public class MyClassThatUsesToggleButton implements  ItemListener{

    //
    // some code
    //
    JToggleButton toggleButton;

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {
            toggleButton.setText("On!");
            totalGUI.setBackground(Color.green);
        }
        else
        {
            toggleButton.setText("Off");
            totalGUI.setBackground(Color.red);
        } 
    //
    // some more code
    //
    }
```

Comment: or you can use the approach, that @Gilbert Le Blanc recommends you...If it's better mine or his depends imho on how many actions you want to catch..